# What was the (alleged) involvement of the Spanish secret services in the 2017 Barcelona terror attack?

Tags: terrorism, spain, catalonia, intelligence

A [tweet](https://twitter.com/josepalay/status/1480947545836765186) is taking off on twitter, claiming a connection between the Spanish secret service (CNI) and the [2017 Barcelona attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2017_Barcelona_attacks):

> Spanish former police chief admits that the Spanish secret services (CNI) were behind the jihadist attacks in Barcelona, August 2017. Their intention was ‘to scare Catalonia just before the independence referendum.’
> 16 people from various nationalities were killed.

It doesn't go into detail what "were behind" means. I found this article on [catalannews.com](https://www.catalannews.com/politics/item/2017-terror-attacks-orchestrated-by-spain-s-secret-service-says-former-police-official) which contains more details, but is also vague on the CNIs exact involvement (it describes the actions as "miscalculation" and "serious mistake").

It also mentions that the alleged mastermind behind the attacks was a CNI informant, but as far as I know that isn't new information.

So it's not exactly clear to me what is being alleged. Was the attack originally the CNIs idea? Did the CNI help plan the attack? Did they know of the attack beforehand and willingly let it happen? Or did they not know of the attack, but had some connection to the terrorists?

Comment: From [Es Satty's article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abdelbaki_Es_Satty) _Satty is believed to have been the mastermind of the planned attacks and to have radicalised the twelve terrorists responsible (...) he was also serving as an informant to Spain's intelligence agency, CNI_. This link is unclear, the Spanish congress vetoed a commission to investigate it and none of the Spanish politicians appeared when required to attend the commission created in the Catalan parliament.

Comment: What is alleged is that CNI were "behind the attacks":  that they planned, organised, financed, equipped, and/or trained the attackers.  What is true is another question altogether.  If this meets the standards required for [skeptics.se] it might be better asked there.

Comment: However the problem with asking "is this true" is that of course CNI aren't admitting it.  Of course there is no evidence. And of course a secret service would have the capability to be behind such an attack and not make it public.  The fact about the secret service is that what they do is secret. And so "is it true" is not likely to have a definite answer